# Default imports with TypeScript

Tags: module, typescript, ecmascript-6

Using tsc 1.8.9... why are these imports not working? I thought TypeScript implemented ES6 module syntax?

"classes/person.ts"

```
export default class Person {
    protected _name: string;
    protected _language: string;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this._name = name;

        this.hello();
    }

    public hello() {
        console.log("Hello, " + this._name);
        console.log("Lang: " + this._language);
    }
}
```

"classes/englishman.ts"

```
import Person from "person"

export default class Englishman extends Person {
    constructor(name: string){
        this._language = "en_GB";

        super(name);
    }
}
```

"main.ts"

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import Englishman from "classes/englishman";

let tom: Person = new Englishman("Tom");
console.log(tom);


$("body").html(`<h1>TEST</h1>`);
```

Errors:

> source/main.ts(2,24): error TS2307: Cannot find module
>   'classes/englishman'. source/main.ts(4,10): error TS2304: Cannot find
>   name 'Person'. [13:53:43] 
>   TypeScript: 2 semantic errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some changes, it worked for me, tested in ES5 and ES6. I hope to help you:

Original

1. `import Person       from "classes/person";`
2. `import Englishman   from "classes/englishman";`

---

Change for test

1. `import Person       from './person';`
2. `import Englishman   from './classes/englishman';`

maybe you need to check your directory tree.

Add

1. `import Person       from './classes/person';`

---

.

```
import Person from './person'; //<-- change

export default class Englishman extends Person {
    constructor(name: string){
        this._language = "en_GB";

        super(name);
    }
}
```

---

```
 export default class Person {
        protected _name: string;
        protected _language: string;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this._name = name;

            this.hello();
        }

        public hello() {
            console.log("Hello, " + this._name);
            console.log("Lang: " + this._language);
        }
    }
```

---

```
import Englishman   from './classes/englishman'; //<-- change
import Person       from './classes/person';     //<-- add

class HelloWorld{
    public static main(){      

        let tom: Person = new Englishman("Tom");
        console.log(tom);

    }
}
HelloWorld.main();
```

---

```
Hello, Tom
Lang: en_GB
Englishman { _language: 'en_GB', _name: 'Tom' }
```

- tsc Version 1.8.2
- node v5.4.1

Comment: Perfect! Adding the `./` worked. I have NO idea why that should be necessary though, since I thought starting from the current directory was a given unless we started with `/`... Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are compiling with ES6 target, if I'm not mistaken, ES5 is still the default target.

Comment: Yes, I believe ES5 was the target. I"m not using Babel or another transpiler, so I believe it should stay ES5.